# Is `group list by size` a fold?

Tags: haskell

I came across this problem : grouping the elements of a list by packet of the same size, so that

```
> groupBy 3 [1..10] 
[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10]]
```

Nothing really hard to do, but first I was surprise that I couldn't find a function for it.
My first try was

```
 groupBy _ [] = []
 groupBy n xs = g : groupBy n gs
              where (g, gs) = splitAt n xs
```

So far so good, it works, even on infinite list. However I don't like the first line `groupBy _ [] = []`. Seems a good candidate for a fold but I couldn't figure it out.

So can this function can be written as a fold or as a one liner ?

## Update

My attempt at a one liner:

```
groupBy' n l = map (map snd) $ groupBy ((==) `on` fst) $ concatMap (replicate n) [1..] `zip` l
```

It took me 10 times more to write that the initial attempt.

## Update 2

Following Ganesh answer and using `unfoldr` and the help of `pointfree` I came out with this convoluted point free solution

```
groupBy' n = unfoldr $ listToMaybe . (ap (>>) (return.splitAt n))
```

Comment: Your original solution is definitely the preferred one. If you had both a `[]` pattern and a `(x:xs)`, then, yes you should have made it a `foldr`, but here you'd need to massage it quite a bit to fit. The obfuscation outweighs any benefits. _Unfold_ as Ganesh suggests works better, because in the _resulting_ list the elements are "on equal standing", while in the input the position mod `n` changes what's done with an element.

Comment: That's the unfold I was looking for.

Comment: If you are interested in a library function, there's `chunksOf` in `Data.List.Split`.

Comment: @bmaderbacher: That's what I was looking for initially. However I couldn't find it on Hoogle. It only find the `Text` version and this after plenty of functions which doesn't have the correct signature.

Comment: @mb14 `Data.List.Split` is part of the Haskell Platform. To search for functions I prefer FPComplete's Hoogle, it has more functions indexed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it as a *fold* with some gymnastics, but it's much nicer as an [*unfold*](http://www.comlab.ox.ac.uk/oucl/work/jeremy.gibbons/publications/unfold.ps.gz):

```
 unfoldr (\xs -> if null xs then Nothing else Just (splitAt n xs))
```

[You'll need to `import Data.List` if you haven't already]

The type of `unfoldr` is:

```
unfoldr :: (b -> Maybe (a, b)) -> b -> [a]
```

The idea of `unfoldr` is that a *generating* function decides whether to stop (`Nothing`) or keep going (`Just`). If the result is `Just` then the first element of the tuple is the next element of the output list, and the second element is passed to the generating function again.

As **@leftroundabout** pointed out in a comment on the question, an unfold is much more natural here because it treats the output list elements as similar to each other, whereas in a fold the input list elements should be treated similarly. In this case the need to start a new sublist every `n` elements of the input list makes this harder.

Comment: I realized `fold` was awkward but needed something in the `fold` family which is indeed `unfoldr`. Is that possible to remove the `if then else` using listToMaybe or something ?

Comment: I can't see anything obvious - `listToMaybe` only returns the first  element of the list. Your alternative is indeed rather convoluted :-)

Comment: If you really like, you can save a few characters with -XLambdaCase: `\n -> unfoldr (\case {[] -> Nothing; xs -> Just $ splitAt n xs})`

Comment: I'm not trying to save characters, I'm just curious about how to remove the `if [] then Nothing` which looks like a classic pattern. My current code use the first version in my post and I'll stick to it.

Comment: @mb14 nice trick with the listToMaybe, though confusing encoding (`ap` and `>>`,`return` from two different monads...). `unfoldr (\xs-> listToMaybe [splitAt n xs | _ <- xs])` is much easier to understand. Or even `unfoldr $ listToMaybe . (map =<< const . splitAt n)`.